# How to display all contents of a Date Modified column in Blender's File Browser

Tags: file-browser

[image]

As you can see in the attached image, my blender's file browser doesn't show all the contents of the Date Modified column. There seems to be insufficient space to display all the content. I tried hovering the mouse cursor over the pipe symbol between columns, but the file browser didn't seem to provide an option to resize the columns. Is there a way to show all the contents of a Date Modified column in the blender file browser?

---

As Gorgious and Gordon Brinkmann speculated, the theme was the cause. I'm a Blender 3.2.0 user and I've tested all the themes and the only thing I found is the Modo theme causing the problem. The rest of the themes show all the contents of the Date Modified column. I opened up all the panels to see if the Modo theme had any effect on the File Browser options, but there were only color related options.
[image]
Why does this only happen with the Modo theme?

---

I noticed that the Modo theme changes the Widget Points value in the Text Style panel.
Other themes default to 11, but the Modo theme is 10. If you change this value to 11, the contents of the Date Modified column are not omitted.
[image]
[image]

Comment: What version are you using ? On my end it is automatically expanded and even goes over the file name when the popup window is resized. You seem to be using a custom theme, maybe there's a setting in the preferences ?

Comment: I would suspect that, too. Or before looking for a setting in the preferences, could you simply switch to a default theme to check if everything's visible? I use the builtin _Blender Dark_ for example and I don't experience this problem.

Comment: This should be a Bug. It's better to report it in bug tracker.

Comment: Reported: https://developer.blender.org/T99207